# Laravel: store json data without backslashes

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel, escaping

I'm trying to insert json data (right now, just fake data) in MySQL, but I'm doing something wrong and I don't see where is the error. Laravel version is 7.4.

Migration file:

```
Schema::create('example_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->json('json_data');
    ...
});
```

The model has the appropiate cast:

```
protected $casts = [
    'json_data' => 'array'
];
```

The factory file:

```
$start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',  '01/01/2020 00:00:00');

$data = array();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $captured_time = $start_time->addMinutes(1);
    $string_date = $captured_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data[] = [mt_rand(0,100),mt_rand(0,100),$string_date];
    $start_time = $captured_time;
}


return [
    'json_data' => json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES),
];
```

The way I would expect the data should be stored on DB is:

```
[[24,55,"2020-01-02 00:01:00"],[29,73,"2020-01-02 00:02:00"],...]
```

(no matter whether is stored with single o double quotes)

But it's stored with backslashes, like this:

```
"[[24,55,\"2020-01-02 00:01:00\"],[29,73,\"2020-01-02 00:02:00\"],...]"
```

Please, anybody knows how to prevent this?
I've tried to store it with the option "JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES" but it looks like it's not working (in case my code is correct).

Note:
While trying to fix it or know where is the origin of the problem I deleted the cast type in the model and it worked but (for me) it has no sense. I think the cast should be on the model so that I don't think this is the solution. Please, let me know if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the json_encode. I think laravel will do it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can put the JSON file in an array using the `array_push` function like this:

```
$new_content=array();
foreach($content as $item){
    array_push($new_content,
               (int)$item['product_id'],
               (int)$item['quantity'],
               trim($item['name_scientific'],
               '"'));
}
```